# Unable to flatten an array of objects into a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to flatten an array of objects. The only real informations i require is the arrays compacted into a single array.

The content is as follows:

```
const content = [
    { "chocolate" : [1] },
    { "banana"    : [5] },
    { "soap"      : [2] },
    { "tea"       : [4] },
];
```

All i am interested in is the values in the array. So desired result would be:

```
const result = [1,5,2,4]
```

I have tried

```
Object.keys(content).map((val) =>  Object.values(content[val]));
```

and even tried creating a function

```
const flatten = ({ children = [], ...rest }) => [rest, ...children.flatMap(flatten)];
```

and calling it like so:

```
 console.log(flatten(content));
```

but no luck.
Help?

Comment: Use flatMap. That is the modern way

Comment: `content.flatMap(Object.values).flat()` or `content.map(Object.values).flat(2)`

Comment: `content.flatMap(obj => Object.values(obj)[0])` will do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to flat-map the entries, and pop the first value off of the object.

```js
const
  content  = [
    { "chocolate" : [1] },
    { "banana"    : [5] },
    { "soap"      : [2] },
    { "tea"       : [4] },
  ],
  numbers = content.flatMap((obj) => Object.values(obj).pop());

console.log(JSON.stringify(numbers)); // [1, 5, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// source variable
const content = [{
  "chocolate": [1]
}, {
  "banana": [5]
}, {
  "soap": [2]
}, {
  "tea": [4]
}]
// to store result value
const result = [];
// lopoping though each object and accesing values of pbject using **Object.values(obj)** an array indexes.
content.forEach(val => result.push(Object.values(val)[0][0]));
// Printing result
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = content.map(o => Object.values(o).shift()[0])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: @Tyler2P, Possibly if I explain in words each part of the code it will be easier to understand what it does. But to what level do I explain, what "const" means, what the "map" function does, what the "Object values" method does.
What does the function "shift() of Array" do, what does the subscript [0] of an Array do?
If you don't understand some of the code, take a part of it and do some research on Google, https://stackoverflow.com/, ChatGpt, etc.
Here nobody is paid to try to help others, and in my opinion everyone helps as they want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `flatMap` with `Object.values`:

```js
const content  = [{"chocolate": [1]}, {"banana": [5]},{"soap": [2]},{"tea": [4]}]
const res = content.flatMap(e => Object.values(e)[0]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

As easy as this `content.flatMap(obj => Object.values(obj)[0])`

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.